# textarea not serialized using jQuery.Serialize()

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization

I've this form

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input id="PostBack_ID" name="PostBack.ID" type="hidden" value="69f1298e-4dce-4f1e-b32d-0a11c273b086" />

  <textarea id="PostBack_Obs" name="PostBack.Obs" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea>
</form>
```

When I serialize the form

```
$("#myForm").serialize();
```

this is what I get

"PostBack.ID=69f1298e-4dce-4f1e-b32d-0a11c273b086"

Why the *textarea* is not seralized?

PD: I'm using the last jQuery version (v3.1.1)

Comment: Should work https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/349/

Comment: yes, if you set the value in the HTML it works but if you leave it empty (like i did) it doesn't work

Comment: Yes it does.  https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/350/

Answer (score 0):

Your approach definitely works:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('body').append('<p>' + $("#myForm").serialize() + '</p>');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm">
  
<input id="PostBack_ID" name="PostBack.ID" type="hidden" value="69f1298e-4dce-4f1e-b32d-0a11c273b086" />

<textarea id="PostBack_Obs" name="PostBack.Obs" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea>
  
</form>
```